# C++ error: undefined reference to function

Tags: c++, g++

I have three files:

Two .cpp files (Reader.cpp and algo.cpp) and one header file (algo.h).

In Reader.cpp file, its function PacketHandler calls a function present in algo.cpp.

**Reader.cpp**

```
void PacketHandler(Packet* sniff_packet, void* user) {
    std::string payload;
    RawLayer* raw_payload = sniff_packet->GetLayer<RawLayer>();
    if (raw_payload) {
        /* Summarize some data */

        cout << "[+] ------- [+]" << endl;
        TCP* tcp_layer = sniff_packet->GetLayer<TCP>();
        cout << "[#] TCP packet from source port: " << dec << tcp_layer->GetSrcPort() << endl;

        cout << "[#] With Payload: " << endl;

                    payload = raw_payload->GetStringPayload();

        SPPM(payload); // Function present in algo.cpp
    }

 }

 void main() { // }
```

**algo.h**

```
#ifndef algo_H_
#define algo_H_
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void SPPM (std::string input);

#endif
```

**algo.cpp**

```
#include "algo.h"

#define byte uint8_t
using namespace std;
void SPPM(std::string input){  //definition }
```

When I compile the code using g++, I get this error:

```
In function `PacketHandler(Crafter::Packet*, void*)':
/home/maleeha/libcrafter_latest/libcrafter-master/libcrafter/pcap_reader.cpp:32:     undefined reference to `SPPM(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,  std::allocator<char> >)'collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am executing my code this way:

```
g++ -c  Reader.cpp -o Reader.o -g -lcrafter
g++   -c  algo.cpp -o algo.o

g++  -o program Reader.o algo.o -lcrafter

./program Packets.pcap
```

Why is this error coming?

Comment: How are you compling it? Sounds like you didn't link the object file for algo.cpp, also why bother with using namespace std if you use std:: everywhere?

Comment: Not sure, but if you are using the std namespace, do you don't need the extra "std::" prefixes everywhere.

Comment: @OldProgrammer that's the wrong way around. They should remove `using namespace std;`, which is just a recipe for future trouble.

Comment: Do you `#include "algo.h"` in Reader.cpp? Also, when you're compiling, you need to give g++ the implementation as well, so the command might be e.g.: `g++ -o reader Reader.cpp algo.cpp`

Comment: @ales_t I have edited my post. I have included how I am compiling the code and yes I am including algo.h in Reader.cpp .Please check.

Comment: @paulm I have edited my post, included the compilation steps.

Comment: @Zara You are misleading us: your command line doesn't mention `pcap_reader.cpp`, yet your error message does. Please show *actual* command, not a vague rendition of it.